# LEFT JOIN runs very slowly, but nested select does not

Tags: mysql, select, nested, left-join

I heard, that JOINS are more efficient, but when i try to implement it, then SELECT is stuck in executing.

I'm using MySQL and I have two tables filled with 100,000 records with a for loop.

```
CREATE TABLE `offers` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY(`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `files` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `path` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `object_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(`id`)
);
```

And following query takes 0,3s to execute:

```
SELECT o.id, (SELECT f.path FROM `files` AS f WHERE f.object_id = o.id LIMIT 1) as path FROM `offers` AS o;
```

But, this query which is working when files table is almost empty in exactly the same way. But when i fill files table, executing never finished.

```
SELECT o.id, f.path FROM `offers` o LEFT OUTER JOIN `files` f ON f.object_id = o.id
```

What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have any indices/references defined?

Comment: No. Is it necessary?

Comment: No .. are useful

Comment: Files table can refer to many others, so I probably can not do this.

Comment: If the files table refers to other tables, you cannot use the same field to reference every table. How would you know if object_id = 1 refers to "offer#1" or "widget#1". That is likely the difference in performance you are seeing; your subquery limits it to one file per offer, but the join pairs offers with every matching file.

Comment: Yes, I know. I have second column which specifies that. But i doesn't added it into topic.

Comment: If there is an additional column that indicates which table the value object_id refers to, you must use it in the join condition and should be using it in the subquery's where condition.

Comment: I agree. After adding the key on this 3 columns, query executes really fast. This is a part of my query which i finally used: "...FROM `offers` AS o LEFT OUTER JOIN `files` AS f ON f.object_id = o.id AND f.type = '1' WHERE... "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for  left join  performance

```
SELECT o.id, f.path 
FROM `offers` o 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `files` f ON f.object_id = o.id
```

be suure you have a composite index

```
  on table files column(object_id, path)
```

Comment: Thanks! This helped.